# Does there exist an infinite dimensional real normed linear space which can be written as a countable union of one dimensional subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Does there exist an infinite dimensional real NLS which can be written as a countable union of one dimensional subspaces ?

I can only tell that if there is a NLS such that it is possible then it cannot be a Banach space by Baire category theorem ( as any one dimensional subspace is closed and being a proper subspace , has empty interior ) .

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: That cannot be done even when the space has dimension $\ge 2$.

Comment: @JohnMa: Finite dimensional NlS are already Banach so I did not include them in my question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every one dimensional subspace of a real normed vector space intersects the unit sphere in two points. Thus, a countable union intersects the unit sphere in at most countably many points and cannot  give the full space (Exercise: show that that the unit sphere is not countable)

Comment: By unit ball I hope you meant $\{x \in X :||x||=1\}$ ; off-course it is uncountable as it is connected in dim $>1$ ... very nice answer ; Thanks

Comment: You are right,  I fixed it